# Adding column in df with function

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, merge

```
      Date             Visitor  V_PTS                 Home  H_PTS  \
0 2012-10-30 19:00:00  Washington Wizards     84  Cleveland Cavaliers     94   
1 2012-10-30 19:30:00    Dallas Mavericks     99   Los Angeles Lakers     91   
2 2012-10-30 20:00:00      Boston Celtics    107           Miami Heat    120   
3 2012-10-31 19:00:00    Sacramento Kings     87        Chicago Bulls     93   
4 2012-10-31 19:30:00     Houston Rockets    105      Detroit Pistons     96
```

Trying to add on to a scraped dataset to do an analysis on NBA game attendance. I'm trying to add a few columns such as arena played and also capacity. Here is a piece of the function I wrote to add the arena. Is there a better way to do this? I have the dates in datetime so how would I extract the year properly to assign the right arena to teams who built newer arenas in the last few years(Sacramento Kings). Also is there anyway to add stadium capacity to this and kill two birds with one stone instead of creating another function?

```
def label_arena (hometeam):
    if hometeam == 'Toronto Raptors' :
        return 'Air Canada Centre'
    if hometeam == 'Miami Heat' :
        return 'American Airlines Arena'
    if hometeam == 'Dallas Mavericks' :
        return 'American Airlines Center'
    if hometeam == 'Orlando Magic' :
        return 'Amway Center'
    if hometeam == 'San Antonio Spurs' :
        return 'AT&T Center'
    if hometeam == 'Indiana Pacers' :
        return 'Bankers Life Fieldhouse'
    if hometeam == 'Brooklyn Nets' :
        return 'Barclays Center'
    if hometeam == 'Milwaukee Bucks' :
        return 'Bradley Center'
    if hometeam == 'Washington Wizards' :
        return 'Capital One Arena'
    if hometeam == 'Oklahoma City Thunder' :
        return 'Chesapeake Energy Arena'
    if hometeam == 'Memphis Grizzlies' :
        return 'FedExForum'
    if hometeam == 'Sacramento Kings' and df['Date'] < 2016:
        return 'Sleep Train Arena'
    if hometeam == 'Sacramento Kings' and df['Date'] > 2016:
        return 'Golden 1 Center'
```

Comment: Use a dictionary and `map` or something similar.  Also, post dataframe as text not an image.

Comment: Minimal - [mcve]

Comment: Man, really seems like you're going to need some kind of a database there, especially if this keeps growing (even if its a text file, a .csv or similar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you can do to simplify your logic:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2012-10-30', '2012-10-30', '2012-10-30',
                            '2012-10-31', '2017-10-31'],
                   'Home': ['Toronto Raptors', 'Los Angeles Lakers', 'Miami Heat',
                            'Sacramento Kings', 'Sacramento Kings']})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

d = {'Toronto Raptors': 'Air Canada Centre',
     'Los Angeles Lakers': 'Staples Center',
     'Miami Heat': 'American Airlines Arena'}

# general criteria
df['Arena'] = df['Home'].map(d)

# custom criteria
df.loc[(df['Home'] == 'Sacramento Kings') &
       (df['Date'].dt.year < 2016), 'Arena'] = 'Sleep Train Arena'
df.loc[(df['Home'] == 'Sacramento Kings') &
       (df['Date'].dt.year >= 2016), 'Arena'] = 'Golden 1 Center'

print(df)

        Date                Home                    Arena
0 2012-10-30     Toronto Raptors        Air Canada Centre
1 2012-10-30  Los Angeles Lakers           Staples Center
2 2012-10-30          Miami Heat  American Airlines Arena
3 2012-10-31    Sacramento Kings        Sleep Train Arena
4 2017-10-31    Sacramento Kings          Golden 1 Center
```

Comment: Awesome this is exactly what I was looking for. Few questions. Am I correct in assuming I can add arena capacity to the dictionary and do a similar thing with that?

Comment: @RayGoncalves, Yup you can do something like that. You can use a dictionary of home team to a tuple of (arena, capacity).

Comment: @RayGoncalves I posted you that in my answer 5 minutes ago.

Comment: is there a way to map these all at once? (arena, capacity,year opened)                                                     `arenas = {'Toronto Raptors' : ('Air Canada Centre',19800,1999),
    'Miami Heat' :('American Airlines Arena',19600,1999),
    'Dallas Mavericks' :('American Airlines Center',19200,2001),
    'Orlando Magic' :('Amway Center',18846,2010),
    'San Antonio Spurs' :('AT&T Center',18418,2001),
    'Indiana Pacers' :('Bankers Life Fieldhouse',17923,1999),`

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

home_arenas_capacities = pd.DataFrame([
     ['Toronto Raptors', 'Air Canada Centre', 20511],
     ['Miami Heat', 'American Airlines Arena', 19600],
     ...
    ]) 

df.merge(home_arenas_capacities, on='Home')
```

For the Sacramento Kings, you want to merge  on both 'Home' and 'Date'> 2016, which may require you to make a temporary column, then `df.merge(..., on=['Home','Date_GE_2016'])` and delete the 'Date_GE_2016' column.

But the cleaner way would be to add a column 'Season' = '2015-16','2016-17'. As your database grows larger seems you'll need that. (For the game database, you can extract 'Season' automatically from the 'Date' value. For the 'home_arenas_capacities' dataframe, you'd need to edit it in manually).

Comment: How would you recommend going about adding the Season column? Sorry to ask so many questions still kind of new and sometimes get overwhelmed trying to google and find these answers. I like the idea cause I also was thinking of adding another column that keeps track of current record and would imagine I'd need to keep track of the season to do it accuratley.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method using [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.select.html), if you're not opposed to `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

conditions = [
    df['Home'] == 'Toronto Raptors',
    df['Home'] == 'Miami Heat',
    df['Home'] == 'Dallas Mavericks',
    ...
    (df['Home'] == 'Sacramento Kings') & (df['Date'].dt.year < 2016),
    (df['Home'] == 'Sacramento Kings') & (df['Date'].dt.year > 2016)]

choices = [
        'Air Canada Centre',
        'American Airlines Arena',
        'American Airlines Center',
        ...
        'Sleep Train Arena',
        'Golden 1 Center']

df['arena'] = np.select(conditions, choices)
```

Note that for your `df['Date']` condition to work, you need to have `df['Date']` set to a datetime Series (you can do this via `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])` if you haven't already done so)